# Getting error while executing visual C++ GUI Program

Tags: forms, visual-c++, c++-cli, linker-errors

I'm getting error,

```
error C1113: #using failed on 'c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.core.dll'
```

When Executing following code...

**MyForm.cpp**

```
#include "Myform.h"

using namespace GUI;  

[STAThreadAttribute]                  
int main(){

    MyForm fm;                       
    fm.ShowDialog(); 
    return 0;
}
```

**MyForm.h**

```
 private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 this->Close();
                 }
```

Comment: More descriptive title would improve the chances your question is discovered and also the usefulness of your question.

Comment: Also, your error occurs when *compiling*, rather than *executing* the code.